# Office JS "TableRowCollection.add" not worked in Excel Online but works well in Excel

Tags: excel, office-js

This code works well in Excel but not works in Excel Online. However, in Excel Online it generate error in browser log, but also insert empty row into table.

I've learn version of API for this function. This seems worked since 2017 in Excel Online.

```
 function onWorksheetAdded(eventArgs) {
 Excel.run(function (context) {
    var table = context.workbook.tables.getItem(INDEX_TABLE_NAME);
    var tableRows = table.rows;
    var tableColumns = table.columns; 
    tableRows.load('items'); tableColumns.load('items');

    return context.sync().then(function () {
        var row = []; for (var j = 0; j < tableColumns.items.length; j++) row.push(0);
        var newRow = [];
        newRow.push(row);
        tableRows.add(0, newRow); //here the mistake, but I can't fix it
        return context.sync();
    });
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
}
```

I've found this in log:
Error: GeneralException: There was an internal error while processing the request. Home.js:204:21
Debug info: {"code":"GeneralException","message":"There was an internal error while processing the request.","errorLocation":"TableRowCollection.add","statement":"var add=rows.add(...);", ...

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: I've just noted, this error depend form Excel table. When I prepare Workbook with table it sometimes do not generate this error. But I can't understand what exactly happened there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add await context.sync(); after tableColumns.load('items') to see whether it can help you.

I did it on my Excel Online with below piece of code, it works well:

```
expensesTable.rows.load('items'); expensesTable.columns.load('items');
await context.sync();

var row = []; for (var j = 0; j < expensesTable.columns.items.length; j++) row.push(0);
var newRow = [];
newRow.push(row);
expensesTable.rows.add(0, newRow);
```

Comment: Sorry, but it still not works. I suppose you have some different environment. I can't using await, because it will fail in Excel (because IE11 may happen there). __How you use it?__  

But when I change __await context.sync()__ for clean JS:
    __return context.sync().then(function () { … }__ 

- it still have same error as described before.

Comment: With __await__ it also do not works in Chrome (Excel Online), where await supported. __Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function__. Which Office JS library you use?